# Calendar: set TimeZone correctly

Tags: java, timezone, java.util.calendar

I would set a TimeZone for Calendar instance but i'm not able to do it. 
I've try with:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd//MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Rosario"));
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

(i've used "America/Rosario" randomly), but i obtain always my current time. What's the right mode to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set timezone in `DateFormat` object:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd//MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Rosario"));

// Will print the formatted date-time in the America/Rosario timezone  
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: PS: Just fyi I didn't check whether `"America/Rosario"` is a valid timezone

Comment: i don't need to use Date() object, but Calendar.

Comment: That's also fine you can use `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();`

Comment: **Live Demo: http://ideone.com/pJtViE** 1st is using `America/Rosario timezone` and 2nd one is default timezone. See the difference in time.